If a feature of a software has to be removed, how to describe it
As a software engineer, sometimes I need to remove some deprecated features from the code base. So how should I describe it?
I usually use "offline feature X" to describe it, but obviously offline is not a verb, so what's the correct way to describe it. Thanks!

Is there a problem with "removed"?

@Mari-LouA remove is ok here, I'm just wondering if there is a more appropriate way to describe it

I'd ask a fellow software engineer, but there are a few on this site, so they might suggest the most appropriate term.

From Stack Overflow, a related question: The Difference Between Deprecated, Depreciated and Obsolete

@Mari-LouA Thanks for your help. the question from stack overflow relates to my question and It helps me understand the differences of these three words which I don't know before.

I’m voting to close this question because I don't think it is about English. IT jargon does not necessarily follow the rules of English grammar, and words borrowed from English to use as jargon do not necessarily translate the same way the equivalent words do in English. Even if this question can be answered by an ELL user because of special knowledge, it is off-topic for the site and could confuse English learners. It would be better directed to a tech site.

Incidental to your question, but in English "software" is not a countable noun. We say "an app" or "a program" or "a piece of software", but not "a software".

@Lambie - Things aren't deprecated. People are  Really?  Deprecate verb past tense: deprecated; past participle: deprecated 1. express disapproval of.
"what I deprecate is persistent indulgence" 2. disparage or belittle (something).
"he deprecates the value of children's television" (Oxford)

@MichaelHarvey Sure, but it refers to a person even there in your example. Only a person can engage in persistence indulgence, not software. Software features cannot be said to be deprecated. Anything else?

@Lambie - We have already seen that things can be deprecated in the field of IT; what is your point?

@MichaelHarvey I have already said: what I deprecate is persistent indulgence. And who exhibits persistance indulgence? Hmm? A person, not a thing. And of course, he deprecates x. People deprecate. That is exactly what I'm saying.  I should have said it like that. A transitive verb (though CGELers will say stative probably).

@Lambie People deprecate Yes. Absolutely. Glad we cleared that up.

I see no reason to close this question.

Programming principle: simple and clear is good. No need to look farther than "remove." I suspect you're looking for terms like "decommission" or "sunset" as a transitive verb, but this kind of corporate-speak is less simple or endless clear. If you want actual lines of code removed, it's best to say so directly.

As I think more about this, I think you can't get an accurate answer until you edit to clarify more about exactly what kind of work you want done. If you want actual lines of code deleted, use "delete" or "remove." If you're deprecating features in your own product, then you're changing how others view and consume it, and other words might be appropriate. (But note, a "deprecated" feature is not removed! It's a warning step before removing it, giving others time to stop using it.)

And if you're addressing places in your code that consume or depend on deprecated external things, then you're presumably also "replacing" or "updating" them.

I've been a long-time Unix/Linux user and small-scale developer, and mixed with mainframe, mini-, and micro- computer users since the early 1980s. I would say that in IT jargon, a deprecated hardware compatibility, feature, way of doing something, or syntax usage is something that exists, is usable, but may be liable to be removed or replaced  in the future. With system utilities,  often these are holdovers from earlier eras where simply removing the feature would break old scripts or programs. Sometimes removal or replacement is not expected, but purists deplore the practice -  Linux users are supposed to avoid a system utility called grep in favour of modern replacements, but this can be hard!

Feature Deprecation Policy
As changes are made to Docker there may be
times when existing features need to be removed or replaced with newer
features. Before an existing feature is removed it is labeled as
"deprecated" within the documentation and remains in Docker for at
least one stable release unless specified explicitly otherwise. After
that time it may be removed.
Users are expected to take note of the list of deprecated features
each release and plan their migration away from those features, and
(if applicable) towards the replacement features as soon as possible.

Deprecated [Docker] Engine Features
As for using 'offline' as a transitive verb meaning 'disconnect, power down or take out of use', I have seen and heard this used about hardware resources such as disks, CPUs, etc, involving mainframes and minis, or modern datacentres. The affected disks will be offlined and possibly cause ASM diskgroups to be forcibly dismounted. Also about network or software resources being taken from an active to an inactive state.

Note: that text uses deprecated in inverted commas.

Use the passive:

This feature has been removed.

Or if you're instructing someone to remove it:

This feature must be removed.
This functionality must be removed.
This function must be removed.



Unshipping is the process of removing a feature or product that has
shipped, and is live, to customers. If teams even evaluate the value
of a feature/product, the conversation revolves around questions such
as,”Why should we keep this feature?” and “What data supports users
actively valuing it?” Both are leading questions since they imply the
feature is advantageous and needs to be defended. Instead of
defaulting to keeping most features, a more balanced approach is
thinking through “Why should you NOT keep this feature?” which we’ll
cover next.
Unshipping* = removing a feature or product that is live to customers
*Other names and phrases for unshipping: killing, reverting, deprecating, sunsetting, rolling back, removing, winding down,
retiring, and obsolescence

The Art of Removing Features and Products
[Personally, I dislike deprecate here. Use it if you want to. I would not.]

Most of all, "deprecate" is used of a feature, product, or service, but not of actual lines of code. I might say "remove these lines because the service they reference has been deprecated," but I wouldn't say "deprecate these lines." But I guess, for that matter, I wouldn't use "unship" of the code itself.

@AndyBonner That does not change this: I need to remove some deprecated features of code. Sure, code is just remove lines of funky code. :)
